# Dexie: How to add an item to the top?

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, dexie

I'm using the Dexie database. To add to the end of the table:

```
tabs.add({}, tabs.getIndex(tabs.getSelected()) + 1)
```

How to add an item to the top of the table?

I tried these options:

```
tabs.add({}, 0)
tabs.add({})
tabs.put({})
```

Comment: There is no "end" or "top", you have to have some value in the data to sort the values by and then retrieve them sorted.

Comment: Sami Kuhmonen, How to do this most easily?

Answer (score 0):

Sami,

One way to get an ordered list of items out of a Dexie table would be to use sortBy()

Here is an example using an imaginary table called messages that has two fields - name and date:

```
db.messages
.where('name')
.equals('fred')
.sortBy('date').then(function(returnedMessages) {
  for (i = 0; i < returnedMessages.length; i++) {
    console.log(returnedMessages[i].date);
  } 
});
```

If you want to reverse the sort use reverse() :

```
db.messages
.where('name')
.equals('fred')
.reverse()
.sortBy('date').then(function(returnedMessages) {
  for (i = 0; i < returnedMessages.length; i++) {
    console.log(returnedMessages[i].date);
  } 
});
```

Hope that helps!

For reference, here are the two documentation pages I sourced for this information:
http://dexie.org/docs/Collection/Collection.sortBy()
http://dexie.org/docs/Table/Table.reverse().html

Frank